# C# backgroundworker loop change label text

Tags: c#, loops, backgroundworker

I have a `Label` in my form and want to change its text every second. I thought that a `BackgroundWorker` is what I need but the while loop in it doesn't seem to work. The first line in the loop does its job but after a `Thread.Sleep` the loop seems to stop.

```
public MainForm()
{           

    InitializeComponent();

    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(getFrame);

    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void getFrame(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(true) {
        ageLabel.Text = "test";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        ageLabel.Text = "baa";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Timer` instead.

Comment: I would also vote for `Timer`. Or, if you still want to use a background worker you better do what you want using `Task.Run(() => { .. Your task here... Task.Delay(1000) .. Your next task here ... })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, use a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Timer);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.1).  Consider this example, where `label1` is a simple `Label` control on a WinForm:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer _timer = new Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void _timer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: why does the `Timer` solution help?

Comment: @MongZhu Wrong question.  Why is a background worker necessary for such a simple task?  The need to invoke to the UI only proves that it's the wrong approach.

Comment: how can my question be wrong? or is this again a wrong question? I wanted to point you to explain why your solution works whereas the one that OP provided does not. Your answer does not adress the issue of the post in any way. Why did the problem arise in the first place?

Comment: @MongZhu `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` fires the event on the UI thread, hence no need to `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: @AlexM Precisely.  Use of a thread here is simply unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Comment: @AlexM "System.Windows.Forms.Timer fires the event on the UI thread," such information belongs into a good answer, and not into the comments, after being asked about it. OP wouldn't have made the mistake if it would have been clear to him

Answer (score 2):

The stopping occurs because you run into a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception which occurs because you try to manipulate a control element from a different thread than it was created on.

To solve your problem you can use [Control.BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx). This method will pull the execution of the control manipulation on the main thread:

```
while (true)
{
    ageLabel.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { ageLabel.Text = "test"; }));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    ageLabel.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { ageLabel.Text = "bla"; }));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

If working with windows forms in visual studio it is adviseable to look into the [output window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hk6fby3.aspx). Exceptions such as this one will be shown there. :)

EDIT: if you simply want to update the UI component property on a timed intervals, you could as well use a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer), which was built for this exact purpose. It is executed on the main UI thread and thus does not need any invocation.

But in general the idea still holds, if you want to manipulate a control from a different thread than it was created on, then you need invocation!

Comment: This is totally unnecessary.  Background threads are for CPU intensive operations, so as to not interfere with the UI.  OP's need, by definition, is a UI operation, so why send it to a thread, only to have to then marshal it back to the UI?

Comment: It is interesting to see that the real correct answer does not have any upvotes

Comment: @DonBoitnott the question show quite clear that OP is learning how to deal with background threads and interact with a GUI.Next time he tries a "CPU intensive operation" and update the GUI to show the progress he will run in exactly the same problem. Still not knowing why da heck it doesn't work. The timer solution might help here in this case, but in my oppinion a good answer should adress the core problem and teach a lesson

Comment: @Mong Zhu - it is definitely worth as a start to explain how things work, but would it not make sense to add that in this (not CPU intense) case a Timer is an easier/optimized solution?

Comment: @AlexM it makes perfect sense to use a timer here. I never disagreed on that. I edited my answer to incorporate this also. Imagine you try to grow food, then you go to someone and say: "I tried to grow potatos in winter, but it does not grow" and he would answer: "Here is 20 bucks go and buy some". How much did you learn about growing food?